# Вывод числа в двоичном виде на ассемблере masm32

Tags: ассемблер, masm

Нужно вывести число, хранящееся в регистре al, на экран в двоичном виде.
В отрывке из кода ниже я делю al на k=2, получаю остаток от деления и вывожу с буфера на экран. Но он не работает)) выдает одно и то же число 01111111.
Есть ли другие способы вывода чисел в двоичном виде на ассемблере?

```
    CYCLE:
jcxz Exit
div k
add ah, 30h
mov buffer_key_2, ah
push ecx
invoke WriteConsoleA, stdout, ADDR  buffer_key_2, 1, ADDR cWritten, 0
pop ecx
dec cx
jmp CYCLE
```